# How to send mock response as a request data to another service trough wiremock

Tags: wiremock

I started working on wiremock recently and I got struck with the below issue

1. I have a soap service which I am mocking through wiremock.
2. I am doing response templating and preparing a dynamic soap response (response should contain some of the request data).
3. whenever this mock service is hit, it has to call another soap service( the service url will be present in the soap requst) with the response(generated in step2)of the mock service as input

i am using the below extensions as dependencies in the pom
```

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-webhooks-extension</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opentable</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-body-transformer</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.json</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>pom.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

```

i tried to run the wiremock with webhook extension like below two ways

```

```
java -jar target/wiremock-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -verbose --extensions com.opentable.extension.BodyTransformer, org.wiremock.webhooks.Webhooks

java -cp "wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar:wiremock-webhooks-extension-0.0.1.jar" com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner --verbose --extensions org.wiremock.webhooks.Webhooks
```

```

4. below is my json.

```

```
{  
   "priority":1,
   "request":{  
      "url":"/services/cv",
      "method":"POST",
      "headers":{  
         "SOAPAction":{  
            "contains":"PutMessage-CV"
         }
      },
      "bodyPatterns":[  
         {  
            "matchesXPath":"//pcc:FamilyName[text()='FRITZ']",
            "xPathNamespaces":{  
               "pcc":"http://www.starstandards.org/STAR"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "response":{  
      "status":200,
      "headers":{  
         "Content-Type":"text/xml; charset=utf-8"
      },
      "bodyFileName":"cv/verified.xml",
      "transformers":[  
         "body-transformer"
      ]
   },
   "postServeActions":{  
      "webhook":{  
         "headers":{  
            "Content-Type":"text/xml; charset=utf-8"
         },
         "method":"POST",
         "bodyFileName":"cv/verified.xml",
         "transformers":[  
            "body-transformer"
         ],
         "url":"//pcc:serviceUrl"
      }
   }
}
```

```

Could you please suggest me how can I achieve this with wiremock.

Thanks,

Comment: I just started reading about `Response Templating`, - https://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/ I think this is where it is discussed about.

Comment: I think, we get response in `REST` regardless to what we mock. In our present work we yet to mock in fact. Other than that. we do get dynamic response, for that we've used the following option in _**WireMock Standalone Service**_  `--global-response-templating` _**: Render all response definitions using Handlebars templates.**_ and we do have done our templating starting with `{{` and ends with `}}`